# Css Calc with current value

Tags: html, css

If I have a setup class like this:

```
.MyClass {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

But then I want to make use of calc to setup the width of components like this:

```
<button class="MyClass" style="width: calc(25% - 10px)"></button>
<button class="MyClass" style="width: calc(25% - 10px)"></button>
<button class="MyClass" style="width: calc(25% - 10px)"></button>
<button class="MyClass" style="width: calc(25% - 10px)"></button>

<button class="MyClass" style="width: calc(75% - 10px)"></button>
<button class="MyClass" style="width: calc(25% - 10px)"></button>

<button class="MyClass" style="width: calc(20% - 10px)"></button>
<button class="MyClass" style="width: calc(30% - 10px)"></button>
<button class="MyClass" style="width: calc(20% - 10px)"></button>
<button class="MyClass" style="width: calc(30% - 10px)"></button>
```

Is there a way to make this more dynamic? So that I can edit the margin in the class and then I don't need to edit the `10px` everywhere else (because I have 100+ buttons). I was hoping for something like this:

```
calc(25% - margin)
```

Comment: Use `bootstrap` for `responsive` page

Comment: Do you have to support IE? Are you willing to use a preprocessor?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that in pure CSS except for having different classes that you apply to the elements. It might be worth it to have a look at CSS preprocessors like SASS/LESS/Stylus where you can use variables. CSS itself also has variables, but [not all currently-used browsers support them yet](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables).

Comment: Or maybe you are looking for [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model)?

Comment: Thanks everyone...and I tried the box-sizing trick but that didn't seem to work?

Comment: Just want to say that it's moronic that CSS lets you use `calc` with a variable but not with a built-in property value like `margin`.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for everyone's answers. I believe this is the easiest solution for now:

```
:root {
    --margin: 5px;
    --marginDouble: var(--margin) * 2;
}

.MyClass {
  margin: 5px;
}

calc(25% - var(--marginDouble))
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn and use CSS variables! It is very simple and powerful. Here is great video tutorial: https://scrimba.com/g/gcssvariables